# Fixed the timezone issue from nextJS API fetching from aws redshift

Tags: javascript, next.js, amazon-redshift, datagrip

I am using Next.js to fetch the data from AWS Redshift while running query from DataGrip its showing

```
orderMonth | repeatC | newC
2024-02-01 |  81     | 122
2024-01-01 | 3189    |4097
```

But while returning from Next.js API same query returning data in timezone

```
orderMonth               | repeatC | newC
2024-02-01T18:30:00.000Z |  81     | 122
2024-01-01T18:30:00.000Z | 3189    |4097
```

I tried to set timezone as well over query but its not working...

I need to have same DataGrip result from API endpoint too.

Any help will be great to identify what the exact reason behind it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data type is this field? Did you try specifying the corresponding format in the Custom Date/Time Formats section of the settings? See https://imgur.com/a/2w6tDMC

Answer (score 0):

To apply custom date time format use *Custom Date/Time Formats* settings in
*Settings | Database | Data Editor and Viewer*

[image: Custom Date/Time Formats]